# Raster R package, points outside the grid

Tags: r, r-raster

I am working on a spatial simulation and I created spatial points, but when I plot them with raster R package I can see that some points are outside the grid. I would like to know how I could be sure that all my points are inside the grid as I need to dynamically change the grid resolution for the next steps of my simulations. Thank you in advance. This is my code for reproductibility:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(100)
tmp = tmp2 = data.frame("x" = rnorm(1000, 10, 10),"y" = rnorm(1000, 10, 10))
coordinates(tmp) <- c("x", "y")
r1 <- raster(tmp, resolution = 10)
r1<-rasterToPolygons(r1)
plot(r1)
for (a in 1:nrow(tmp2)) {
  d = tmp2[a,]
  pts<- d
  coordinates(pts)<-~x+y
  plot(pts,add=T,col=a)
}
```

**EDIT 1**: Trying to define raster base on min and max values of XY coordinates, but some points are still outside the grid (visible in the plot)

```
library(raster)
set.seed(100)
tmp = tmp2 = data.frame("x" = rnorm(1000, 10, 10),"y" = rnorm(1000, 10, 10))
coordinates(tmp) <- c("x", "y")

r1 <- raster(xmn = min(tmp2$x), xmx = max(tmp2$x), 
              ymn = min(tmp2$y), ymx = max(tmp2$y), 
              resolution = 10)

r1<-rasterToPolygons(r1)
plot(r1)
for (a in 1:nrow(tmp2)) {
  d = tmp2[a,]
  pts<- d
  coordinates(pts)<-~x+y
  plot(pts,add=T,col=a)
}
```

Comment: Are you asking, how do I generate a random sample from a normally distributed population where all values are guaranteed to fall within an interval? Technically you don't as if it's bounded it's no longer a normal distribution, but all samples (and populations) have a max and min value so it's a reasonable goal as long as you keep the caveat in mind. Anyway there are some methods [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113230/generate-random-numbers-following-a-distribution-within-an-interval).

Comment: No, my points are generated differently in my simulation. The issue is that from a XY data frame when I create a grid through lines 5-6 some points are outside the grid. For the next step of my research I need to use grid coordinates rather than XY coordinates but I end up with Na values

Comment: So is your goal to create a raster of a certain resolution and generate random points inside it? Or is it that you already have the points, but they are not being plotted in `r1`?

Comment: I already have the points but some of them are outside the grid

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253281/plotting-points-extracted-from-a-dataframe-in-a-raster-layer) answer your question?

Comment: not really, because xmn, xmx, ymn, ymx are defined arbitrarily. But even when trying to define raster base on min and max values of XY coordinates, some points are outside the grid (visible in the plot)